# open file location with as3

Tags: file, actionscript-3, air

I have a `<s:List />` that contain a bunch of `files`. On right click I open a menu at the (x, y) position of the mouse that lets the user "Open File Location". My struggle is opening the file location and selecting (without opening) the file much like Window's explorer. The closest I have come in opening the parent folder and using `file.openWithDefaultApplication();`, which opens the folder that the file is in without showing the user the actual file.

**mxml**

```
        <s:List
            id="fileDownList"
            height="100%"
            width="100%"
            dataProvider="{files}"
            labelField="name"
            allowMultipleSelection="false"
            rightClick="rightMouseDown(event)"
            itemRollOver="currentItem = event.itemRenderer.data"
            />
```

**AS3**

```
    private function rightMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
        createMenu(currentItem, event.stageX, event.stageY);
    }

        private function createMenu(item:Object, xPos:int, yPos:int):void {
        if (menu != null) {
            menu.hide();
        }
        var menuItems:Array = [];

        menuItems.push({label:"Open File Location"),
            func: function run():void{
                //runs on doMenuAction listener, need to open location here

            }

        });

        if (menuItems.length > 0) {
            menu = Menu.createMenu(tree, menuItems);
            //noinspection JSValidateTypes
            menu.addEventListener(MenuEvent.ITEM_CLICK, doMenuAction);
        }

        if (menu != null) {
            menu.show(xPos, yPos);
        }

    }
```

**Example**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Also – browser-based? AIR?

Comment: @Sleeper what part is unclear so I may clarify? This is an AIR desktop application.

Comment: @Sleeper, have you ever used Windows file search?? when it gives you a list of file names you can right-click one and choose "open file location" which opens a new Explorer window and automatically scrolls down to the said file where it's automatically highlighted / selected for you...

Comment: @Jordan.J.D, I dont know if that will be possible. Maybe there's a windows CMD terminal command that you could execute (as NativeProcess?) to highlight expected file. You'll have to google around and see

Comment: @VC.One i will keep looking for possible solutions, I added some images and a bit of code. Thank you.

Comment: @Sleeper, let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a .cmd file (just a renamed .bat file) that opens up a directory with the `/select` argument on the file.

**AS3**

```
private function run():void{
                        var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
                        var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\launcher.cmd");
                        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

                        var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
                        processArgs[0] = item.url;
                        nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;

                        process = new NativeProcess();
                        process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);

                    }
```

**launcher.cmd**

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /a LOCATION=%1
explorer /select, %1
```

Answer (score 2):

Gave it a try... Turns out **it is possible** using NativeProcess and some `Explorer.exe` parameters.

Heres a basic AS3 only example. Please test and then apply the logic in your code :

```
//# String holds required file path
//# example ::: myfileURL = "C:\\myFolder\\mySubFolder\\myImage.jpg";
public var myfileURL : String = "";

myfileURL = "C:\\VC1\\Tests\\CoolSong.mp3"; //update this before running function
openWindows_FileSelected(); //run the function

private function openWindows_FileSelected ():void  
{  
    var explorer:File = new File("C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe");

    if (explorer.exists)  
    {  
        var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();  
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = explorer;  

        var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();  

        args.push("/select,"); 
        args.push( myfileURL ); //file to auto-highlight

        nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;  
        process = new NativeProcess();  
        process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);  
    }  

}
```

**PS:**

The only gotchas I can think of... Since you're using `File` you'll have to get a string of its path via File's `.nativePath` command which gives a String like : 
 
`"C:/myFolder/mySubFolder/myImage.jpg"` 
 
but for the above code to work you must do a replace (try the String method `Split/Join`) and have it looking like : 
 `"C:\\myFolder\\mySubFolder\\myImage.jpg"`. 
If you dont replace all single forward-slash with double back-slashes then `Explorer.exe` wont like it and you'll always get an error...

Comment: Files have a `url` property that you can use instead of split and join.

Comment: Ah!! Should've thought of that. Still new to AIR-based code. Your question is my third ever attempt with it. Only ever needed to re-compile AS3 code to Android.